# What additional restrictions are imposed by managing state in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I read that storing state in Redux (as opposed to within a component), imposes additional restrictions on how state can be mutated, but it's not clear what these are.

As far as I know, even when managing state within a component, state is always supposed to updated immutably. For example, if our current state is

```
{
  count: 3
  list: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
}
```

If we want to increment the count by 1 and add an item to the list, the correct way to do this (when the state is stored in a component) is:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return { 
    count: prevState.count + 1,
    list: prevState.list.concat('another')      
  };               
});
```

If we were to store the state in Redux and modify it by dispatching an action to a reducer, AFAIK we're supposed to modify it an similarly immutable fashion.

In term of updating the state, does storing it in Redux impose additional restrictions?

Comment: Where exactly did you read it?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I can't remember

Comment: Ok, not sure what exactly the article meant when it says `storing state in Redux (as opposed to within a component), imposes additional restrictions on how state can be mutated`, but I feel the only overhead comes with dispatching actions to update the state. for each state a update a new action needs to be dispatched. apart from it a new updated state is all you need to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would work (almost) the same way in a reducer. You're returning a new object that's based on the previous state, this exactly what redux wants you to do.

But note that unlike React's `setState`, **you need to return the entire state** in a reducer. Often `Object.assign` or the `...` operator is used to accomplish this: `return { ...state, changedThing: 'value' };`. Whereas in React, `setState({ changedThing: 'value' })` is enough.

That would be your additional restriction then I guess.